# I need help about Input Filter

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-inputfilter

I have this method in Model TaiKhoan

```
public function getInputFilter()
{
   if (!$this->inputFilter) 
   {
      $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
      $factory     = new InputFactory();

      $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name'     => 'TenTaiKhoan',
            'required' => true,
            'filters'  => array(
                  array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                  array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
            ),
      )));

      $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name'     => 'MatKhau',
            'required' => true,
            'filters'  => array(
                  array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                  array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
            ),
      )));
   }

   return $this->$inputFilter;
}
```

Then i used it in my Controller like

```
$taikhoan = new TaiKhoan();
```

$form->setInputFilter($taikhoan->getInputFilter());

When i run, it show me this error

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\ZF\module\CPanel\src\CPanel\Model\TaiKhoan.php on line 59
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a typo in this statement:

```
return $this->$inputFilter;
```

PHP is interpreting this line as a dynamic property name, and this converting it to a string. The correct version is:

```
return $this->inputFilter;
```

Also you need to assign something to the input filter:

```
public function getInputFilter()
{
    if (!$this->inputFilter) 
    {
        // ...
        $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
    }

    return $this->inputFilter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are lazy loading the input filter, but never setting `$this->inputFilter`.

```
public function getInputFilter()
{
    if (!$this->inputFilter)
    {
        $this->inputFilter = new InputFilter();
    }
    return $this->inputFilter;
}
```

Not sure if this is your problem because the error is about casting your input filter to a string. Please provide the exact code on line 59 of TaiKhoan.php.